# Отправка данных формы с выпадающим списком

Tags: forms, php, form

Я написал код формы:

```
<form method='post' action='admin.php'>
<table width='100%' style='color:white'>
<tr><td>Категория:</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name='category'>
        <option value='houses'>Участки</option>
        <option value='clothes'>Одежда</option>
        <option value='people'>Симы</option>
        <option value='animals'>Петы</option>
        <option value='others'>Разное</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Название файла:</td><td><input type='text' name='name'></td></tr>
<tr><td>Прямая ссылка на файл:</td><td><input type='text' name='link'></td></tr>
<tr><td>Описание файла:</td><tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><textarea cols='50' rows='5' name='description'></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>Скриншот:</td><tr>
<tr><td><input type='file' name='image'></td><tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><center><input type='submit' value='Отправить' name='submit' class='button'></center></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Теперь у меня в select каждое option имеет value='houses' и т.д. и т.п. Обработка...

```
if (@$_POST['submit']) {
    $bd="bd/".$_POST['category'].".dat";
    $name        = $_POST['name'];
    $link        = $_POST['link'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $name        = htmlspecialchars($name);
    $link        = htmlspecialchars($link);
    $description = htmlspecialchars($description);
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($link) && !empty($message)) {
        $path     = "images/fileimages/";
        $tempfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $newname  = $path . "/" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $img      = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        if (is_uploaded_file($tempfile)) {
            copy($tempfile, $newname);
        }
        $text = "$name:::$link:::$description:::$img";
        $fh   = fopen($bd, "a");
        fwrite($fh, "$text\n");
        fclose($fh);
    }
}
```

Мне надо, чтобы при выборе из `select`, например, "Участки", в `$bd` записывалось значение `houses` и т.п., но этого не происходит, потому что в файл ничего не добавляется. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ivanforpw, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fh   = fopen(filebd, "a");
```

меняете на

```
$fh   = fopen($filebd, "a");
```

А при записи данные лучше сериализировать.

```
$cat = $_POST['category']; //в твоем случае $bd
$data = array('category' => $cat, 'name' => $name, 'link' => $link, 'desc' => $description, 'img' => $img);
$write = serialize($data);
$fh = fopen($filebd, "a");
fwrite($fh, $write);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: я насчёт $filebd заметил уже, поменял на $bd, где $bd="bd/".$_POST['category'].".dat";
Но сама проблема в передаче селекта, как из option передать значение house или другое и это значение приписать к $bd в обработке?

Comment: мне не надо передавать значение селекта в файл, мне нужно чтобы значение селекта была равна значению имени файла, куда этот текст весь и записывать, конечно +.dat(формат)

Comment: $filebd      = 'bd/'.$bd'.dat'; // Если есть директория bd
 $fh = fopen($filebd, 'w');

Comment: всё сделал сам, просто убрал    if (!empty($name) && !empty($link) && !empty($message)) {...} ;)